# Formatting Canadian postal codes with .splice()

Tags: javascript

I need to properly format a Canadian zip code if its entered in wrong.

Format is ### ### where "#" can be either a number or letter for example : M5R 2G3

I've tried this: (its broken up for testing purposes)

```
  shipping.zip = shipping.zip.toUpperCase().split('')

  shipping.zip = shipping.zip.splice(3, 0, ' ')

  shipping.zip = shipping.zip.join().replace(/,/g, '');
```

But when I enter in :

> m5r2g3

I Get this:

> [ 'M', '5', 'R', '2', 'G', '3' ]
>
> [ ]

And thats it. I have no idea why its not working. Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
'm5r2g3'.toUpperCase().replace(/\W/g,'').replace(/(...)/,'$1 ') // "M5R 2G3"
```

The `replace(/\W/g,'')` removes all non-alphanumeric characters (including commas).

Comment: Holy crap batman that was impressively simple. I need to up my regEx skills. Thanks.